# Need core plot with coloured vertical line at each data x coordinate, with height data y coordinate

Tags: iphone, charts, core-plot

I would like to use core plot to chart my data as follows: for each data point (x,y), draw a vertical line starting at (x,0) and running to (x,y).

The data are medication doses, mapped against time of dose.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a bar plot. Set `barsAreHorizontal = NO` to make vertical bars. Use `barWidth`, `lineStyle`, and `fill` to customize the appearance. Several of the example programs use bar plots—look at them for ideas.

Comment: My understanding of a bar plot is that it divides the data range into buckets and displays the average y value for each bucket. So, the bars cover the entire range. For my application, I would like a line for each and every data point, with height equal to the y value of that point. If I can do this with a bar plot, that would be fabuluous.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Core-Plot";

    graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    CPTheme *theme = [CPTheme themeNamed:kCPDarkGradientTheme];
    [graph applyTheme:theme];

    CGAffineTransform verticalFlip = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,-1);

    UILabel *lbl;
    for( int i = 21; i <= 24; i++ ){

        lbl = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
        lbl.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(verticalFlip, 0, -300);
    }   

    CPLayerHostingView *hostingView = (CPLayerHostingView *)self.view;
    hostingView.hostedLayer = graph;
    graph.plotArea.masksToBorder = NO;

    graph.paddingLeft = 50.0;
    graph.paddingTop = 60.0;
    graph.paddingRight = 20.0;
    graph.paddingBottom = 50.0;

    CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(6)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(([[expectedCigArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue]+5))];
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction=YES;

    CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    CPXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.axisLineStyle = nil;
    x.majorTickLineStyle = nil;
    x.minorTickLineStyle = nil;
    x.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromString(@"1");
    x.constantCoordinateValue = CPDecimalFromString(@"0");
    x.title = @"Days";
    x.titleLocation = CPDecimalFromFloat(1.5f);

    CPXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.axisLineStyle = nil;
    y.majorTickLineStyle = nil;
    y.minorTickLineStyle = nil;
    y.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromString(@"5");
    y.constantCoordinateValue = CPDecimalFromString(@"0");
    y.title = @"Money";
    y.titleOffset = 30.0f;
    y.titleLocation = CPDecimalFromFloat(10.0f);


    CPBarPlot *expectedMoney = [CPBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPColor darkGrayColor] horizontalBars:NO];
    expectedCigPlot.identifier = @"expectedCigPlot";
    expectedCigPlot.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
    expectedCigPlot.barWidth = 15.0f;
    expectedCigPlot.dataSource = self;
    [graph addPlot:expectedCigPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];

}


-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot{
    return (moneyArray.count + 1);
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{   
    if(fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldX)
    { 
        return [NSNumber numberWithInt: index];
    }
    else
    {
        if(plot.identifier == @"money")
        {
            if(index == 0)
                return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0];
            return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[moneyArray objectAtIndex:(index-1)] doubleValue]];
        }

    }
}
```

Note that in the above code money array has value of money, So I think your purpose can be solved by passing the y value in the array.